# How To Check IIS Logging Status Via Command Line

Tags: powershell, logging, iis, command

Looking online, I have not seen any information on how to capture the status of the logging function on the IIS console and I was hoping to see if anyone knew how to do this via cmd/PowerShell? I am trying to see if the logging component is enabled/disabled via the command-line interface.

Comment: Have a read of these which should get you started, once you have a powershell script which you need help with update your question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the below PowerShell command to check the iis logging is enabled or not and other details:

```
Import-Module -Name WebAdministration

Get-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name logfile
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the assistance, I have just tested the PowerShell command and it seems even if the logging setting is set to disable, the enabled line within the command output is set to True at all times. I have also, restarted the IIS service to make sure the disable/enable setting is successfully enforced.